# What data "MUST" be stored inside a "relational database"?

Tags: database-design, application-design, design-pattern, physical-design, single-table-design

I am working on a mobile/web app like Instagram. Considering that, I want to know for what part of the app it's better to use `relational` and for what other parts `non-relational` databases.

I have chosen `MySQL` and `Cassandra` databases and this is my research result so far:

`-Relational Databases`:

- For services we need as much as possible consistency like `payment` service or `ordering` and `authentication` services.

`- Non-relational Databases`:

- For services we need to summarize a lot of different data in a small table instead of a lot of columns with null values, like `user` services that we have a lot of personal settings.
- For the time we need horizontal scalability and want more distributed system over different datacenters/clouds.
- For faster read/write heavy systems.

But I am still wondering to know:

1- What database is more appropriate for upload files(images, videos. documents) on it?

2- What database is more sufficient for posts/comments/likes, list of friends, and other user related things that they are also related to other users. (***I mean a post or a comment is related to one user but all the other users can also see it, and may affect them***).

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, relational databases are great when the data itself has natural relationships.  For example, if you're storing data that relates to a specific user, you would want to have that stored in a relational database, to enable the data to be related consistently with the user.

NoSQL databases, on the other hand, are great when storing data that is inconsistent for example storing documents.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. From my research so for, `authentication`, `ordering` and `payment` services are the best use cases for relational databases. But I still wondering to know what other services are good to go with `relational` databases? (I have also updated my question).

Comment: Considering `Instagram` as a study case, could you say what other services may fit better with a `relational` database? Or answer the other questions in my updated question.